# Enter in Quickfix window gives "E73: tag stack empty" error

Tags: quickfix, plugin-lid.vim

I am using the Lid.vim plugin to navigate my C++ project. 
Once I run `:Lid`, it shows me the list of matching tags in the quickfix window.

When I switch to the quickfix window, select the occurence I'm interested in and press `Enter` it produces an error:

```
E73: tag stack empty
```

and does not go to the location.

Instead of `Enter` if I use `Ctrl-Enter` it opens a new window and goes to the location correctly.

I want to open the quickfix location in the current window itself. Why is this error happening?

Comment: Maybe that's something you should [talk about with the author](https://github.com/yegappan/lid/issues).

Comment: This is not just the Lid.vim plugin. I have had this issue with ctags as well before.

Comment: `Enter` is implemented internally as `:.cc` (it's actually `:.cc` for quickfix lists and `:.ll` for location lists).  Does the problem still occur if you run `:cc`?

Comment: Using `:.cc` works . But Enter is not. Why is that?

Comment: You have a plugin that maps `Enter` to something else.

Comment: the mapping is introduced by the line `map <C-m> :tnext<CR>`. When i remove this line, there is no mapping for <CR> but when i add it, there is  mapping for <CR> . Any idea why?

Comment: I got the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935970/vim-how-to-map-ctrl-m-without-affecting-return-keypress-as-well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that i had  a mapping `map <C-m> :tnext<CR>` in my vimrc . 
In vim, `<C-m>` is equivalent to `Enter`. 
More detailed answer at [how to map Ctrl-m without affecting return keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935970/vim-how-to-map-ctrl-m-without-affecting-return-keypress-as-well)